# Datetime Parameter In CRM report run invalid

Tags: datetime, reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011, ssrs-2012

I'm Working with SSRS Report in CRM Then I have problem about DateTime Parameter before run report below.

**First, I choose date from Datetime Picker below** 
[image]

**Then TextBox show**
[image]

**In fact It's should show Only date But why it's show Date & Time**
And after i Choose anything in parameter section Parameter always refresh and I surely I set automatic determine in .rdl file (from my experience its should not refresh)

**Second, When I choose first date of month** 
[image]

**TextBox show**
[image]

Its show.

> *8-Jan-15*

So My Question is.

1. Why Text Box show Invalid value.
2. Why its always refresh when i choose paremeter.
3. And How to fix it.

Thank you.

(I think I not happen for .rdl file)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know CRM but in SSRS I would say

1. This seems to be a bug in CRM with using other date formats: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/138318
2. Parameters refresh in case other parameters are dependent on the previous parameter.
3. You can't fix the refresh, you can try changing your system date format but that's not a good fix. You can try this:
   http://geekswithblogs.net/naijacoder/archive/2008/06/26/123422.aspx